# ESRI TypeError: this.spatialReference is undefined

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I'm using Esri GIS to load center location from address. But I use geocoder from google to get longitude and latitude. I'm stuck with this error:

```
TypeError: this.spatialReference is undefined
```

Do you have any idea for this problem?
this is my code:

```
require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", "esri/graphic",  "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", "dojo/domReady!" ],
                function(Map, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, PictureMarkerSymbol, Graphic, GraphicsLayer) {

             var point = new Point(0, 0, new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: gisMap['wkid'] }));
             map = new Map(mapHolder, {center: point,zoom: gisMap['zoomlevel']});
             var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();     
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': keyword}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var  latitude= results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        console.log(longitude+"|"+latitude);
                        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                            map.centerAt(new Point(longitude,latitude));
                            console.log(map);

                        } else {
                              console.log("No results found");
                        }
                    } else {
                      console.log("Something got wrong " + status);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: which line of code throws that error? your code never uses `this`, so it's a lottery

Comment: Not sure because it been some time since I used it, but don't you have to add "esri/SpatialReference" in your require, and then use it like new SpatialReference instead of new esri.SpatialReference?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your initialization of the new esri.SpatialReference. You're not actually providing any information -- wkid is short for 'well known ID' and doesn't actually communicate any information to the API.

Since you didn't specify the version of the JS API you're using (3.x and 4.x are quite different), I can't post proper code to show you how it should be done, but these two resources: 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-SpatialReference.html

and

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/spatialreference-amd.html

should show you how the method should be used!